# Изменить пароль пользователя в настройках роли при смене пароля пользователя на удаленном хосте ansible

Tags: ansible

Имеем Ansible, роль common_users, которая создает на хостах пользователей, с предустановленным паролем. Пароль юзера одинаков на всех хостах.

Далее сценарий: пользователь меняет свой пароль на одном из хостов.

Проблема в следующем:

Как изменить пароль в конфигах роли Ansible, чтобы при следующем проходе Ansible пароль юзера изменился на остальных хостах.

Comment: Краткий ответ: "никак" и "не надо такие сценарии разрешать". Расписал подробно ответом, в поле комментария не помещается.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Допустим есть роль server_admin, в которой вы создаёте спец. пользователя admin.

Файл `roles/server_admin/tasks/main.yml`:

```
- name: add special user
  user:
    name={{ server_admin.login }}
    password={{ server_admin.password }}
```

В реальности, конечно, нужно бывает сразу предусмотреть список спец. пользователей (ну а вдруг понадобится больше одного?), что-то вроде:

```
- name: add special users
  user:
    name={{ item.username}}
    password={{ item.password }}
    groups=wheel
  with_items:
    - "{{ server_admins.special_userss }}"
```

но будем считать, что нужно создать одного.

При этом у нас в роли есть настройки где хранится логин и пароль спецпользователя, файл `roles/server_admin/defaults/main.yml`:

```
server_admin:
  login: "admin"
  password: "$6$rounds=40000$vx8fkGJ1A5ucZQuasdfasdfasdfa58TuC38M3yrkCYL6l/"
  ssh_key_file: "files/ssh_keys/admin.pub"
```

Таким образом задаются настройки пользователя.

Если вы будете каждые сутки в полночь запускать скрипт обновления паролей -- то на тех серверах, где пользователь поменял пароль он будет восстановлен.

Всё это разумеется верно, если не менялся пароль на учётную запись ansible из-под которой он работает (кто-то оставляет root, я для этого создаю и держу спец. учётку)

---

А вот в обратную сторону есть закавыки.

Нет способа для такого сценария: как только пользователь на одном из серверов поменяет пароль -- он тут же будет передан на центральный сервер ansible в специальный скрипт, который поменяет конфиги.

Ansible больше ориентирован на модель push, а не pull: изменения идут с центрального (командного сервера) на клиенты, а не клиенты периодически опрашивают центральный сервер на предмет нет ли изменений.

Но даже если и так, то я не знаю, как из системной утилиты смены пароля вытащить пароль: подозреваю, что такой дырки в системе просто не оставлено.

А не зная пароля и нет смысла городить обратную цепочку по забросу пароля обратно. (Такая цепочка в принципе возможна, но уж больно хлопотна -- да и не особо и нужна)

Чисто умозрительно, если у вас на клиентских машинах есть возможность отследить событие смены пароля и по этому событию запустить скрипт, в который передавать пароль -- то вам можно на каждый клиенсткий сервер, где возможна процедура смены пароля, поставить ansible со специальным скриптом, который будет подключаться к серверу и модицифировать конфиг-файл, но это громоздко, костыльно и жутко небезопасно.

Я предлагаю отказаться от этого сценария вообще. Не нужно вообще менять пароль на клиентских машинах -- от слова совсем. Меняйте его на сервере ансибл в конфиге -- и отправляйте на остальные машины.

Такая модель весьма проста: центральный сервер считается хранителем эталонной конфигурации, а все отклонения от неё на клиентах -- это нештатные ситуации, которые требуют исправления.

Дело касается не только паролей, но и любых других вещей. Скажем, хочется поменять строчку в конфиге nginx, чтобы увеличить лимит на размер загружаемых файлов -- изволь сделать это на сервере ансибл, а не ковыряй локальный конфиг, надеясь, что он потом сам загрузится на центральный сервер и сохранится в качестве эталонного образца для всех серверов.

Кроме того, ничто не запрещает иметь дефолтный пароль (мы его задаём на уровне роли) для большинства серверов и какой-то индивидуальный для одного нестандартного сервера (просто переопределите для нужных серверов пароль в host_vars).

Update Кстати, когда вы сказали, что можно отловить какой-нибудь файл я подумал вот о чём. Насчёт дополнительных инсталляций ansible: они действительно не нужны. Можно на управляющем сервере запускать кроном скрипт ансибл, который будет выполнять проверку удалённых файлов и по существованию файла запускать обработчик со сменой паролей.

Закавыка по-прежнему именно в том, что вы не сможете сделать так, чтобы при смене пароля пользователем пароль писался бы в файл. Вот это делает схему неработоспособной.

Также перенесу из комментария мысль, которую я обдумывал вчера. Вам нужно смотреть в сторону LDAP -- это как раз каталог, который при смене пользователем пароля меняет его в централизованном хранилище.

Update 2. Насчёт `/etc/shadow` (беглое гугление подсказывает, что там хранится md5 от пароля): если бы ansible умел подставлять от md5пароля (сейчас может применяться либо сам пароль, либо sha_512 -- уточнить, можно ли как-то подсунуть именно md5) то написание такого скрипта, который вы хотите в принципе стало бы вполне непростой, но вполне реальной задачей.

С тем ограничением, что если пароль меняется сразу на двух и более хостах, то результат непредсказуем -- какой-то хост обработается раньше и этот пароль будет перетёрт информацией с другого хоста.

Comment: Спасибо

>>Ansible ... изменения идут с цен ..
Но ведь при push Ansible видит изменения в конфигах на удаленном хосте, в том же shadow и вместо того чтобы переписать его, он бы менял строку "password: "$6$rounds=40000$vx8fkGJ1A5ucZQuasdfasdfasdfa58TuC38M3yrkCYL6l/"" в своих конфигах.
Я думал, что можно как-то получить какую-то переменную, базируясь на значении которой можно было бы запустить локальный handler для перезаписи локального конфига

>>Меняйте его на сервере ансибл

Для этого нужно знать пароль юзера, а он также удаленный и не может подойти для смены своего пароля

Comment: @user2144190 Для единой парольной базы подходит Active Directory, LDAP или прочие вещи. А изменения в файлах ловятся легко, это не пароль, который никуда не сохраняется и на экране не показывается, увы, другое.

Comment: @user2144190 Добавил в ответ ещё немного.

Comment: @user2144190 Кстати. Если в /etc/shadow хеш пароля подойдёт для скармливания ansible -- то написание такого скрипта становится вполне реальной.

Comment: >>Если в /etc/shadow хеш пароля подойдёт для скармливания ansible... подойдет, юзеров создаю указывая в password именно хеш. По поводу скрипта для отлавливания момента смены пароля вижу только подмену /bin/passwd на свой скрипт. Просто думал, что у Ansible есть внутренние возможности

Comment: @user2144190 Хеши бывают разные. Я следую рекомендациям ansible и создаю данные для паролей через `python -c "from passlib.hash import sha512_crypt; print sha512_crypt.encrypt('password')"`, поэтому не уверен, что подойдут те же самые хеши, что в `/etc/shadow`. Но если подойдут -- то я вижу другую альтернативу подмене `/bin/passwd/`: можно тупо выцеплять через awk нужную строку и через `register_variable` получать переменную с новым паролем. [пример](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041208/in-ansible-how-do-i-export-an-environment-variable-in-one-task-so-it-can-be-use/39041402#39041402)

Comment: Про md5: похоже, что нет. В документации только про sha512. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/user_module.html